# Application vs Service vs Intent

Tags: android, service, android-intent, bluetooth

I am creating a project which connects to an embedded Bluetooth chip. Currently I have it set up with a separate application class which controls all the bluetooth functionality.

My program initialized with a main menu that has 9 buttons. In the main screen I create the connection to the Bluetooth device. Each button brings me to a separate Activity. Each activity needs to receive different pieces of data from the Bluetooth chip.

My question to you all is, would it make sense for me to use a service instead of an application? From what I understand of a service, it is used because there is always something running in the background. However in this case nothing needs to be running in the background ( unless keeping the connection with the Bluetooth device counts), data is only sent/received when an Activity asks for it.

Or, am I completely off track and shouldn't use either? Just a simple class to act as my data container which can be passed through intents? I know this will work, but am very new to Android and intents seem to be a bit messy. I would rather not use intents if I didn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also building up a bluetooth connection, and i put the whole communication stuff in a service and bind to this service with every activity that needs to use the connection. This works pretty well for me. You might want to choose this way too.

Actually i earlier realised a way holding the connection in the application, but now i prefer the service way, because i'm using the application for global states.

Using service also reduces the need of intents to a very small amount :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case a static property for the bluetooth connection would be the most pragmatic solution

Comment: This is not very informative. What do you mean by a static property.

Comment: I mean creating a static property in some class, such as BluetoothContainer.connection, which will be thus accessible to all activities of the application. You can wrap it with a static getter and call it Singleton, if you want. Of course it has a limitation - you can have only one connection, but it seems that the OP doesn't need more than one.

Comment: I think this sounds like what I want. But as I said I am very new to android. Would this just be a class on its own, not a subclass? How would I access this from other activities? Intents?

Comment: Even if it sounds surprising, the static properties are shared among all activities of the app. So you make it static, and just use wherever you need it directly by [clasname].[property] , don't need to pass it.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit slow with Android/Java. I can create a static CLASS, called Bluetooth.class, and all Activities in my app can call Bluetooth.field, Bluetooth.method(), and so on as long as they are public? How and where would the connection be initialized?

Comment: no, you need a static property, a static class in not needed - see the example http://pastebin.com/cUziyyeR

Comment: Ah, so a static field in ANY activity can be called from any other Activity, as long as the Activity it was initialized in was never closed?

Comment: that's true. Moreover any class can access any static property of any other class, no matter if there were any objects or not (because it belongs to the class, not the objects), as long as you're in the same application.

Comment: Ok, so I have one more question. If I make a static instance of a class, to access every method/field within that object, to they all need to be static as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13364/discussion-between-disjunction-and-juice)